# Powdery plaster with paint peeling

Tags: repainting

Brick house 20 years old has plaster that seems to have never been properly sealed.  Paint is coming off in large peeling patches. To repaint, after removing any loose paint, how can I seal surface where some is raw plaster and some is old paint?

Comment: Is there any evidence of moisture coming through the plaster?

Comment: No moisture, just crap plaster work.

Comment: Where the previous paint was poorly-adhering water-based emulsion, I used liberally-thinned emulsion-paint as a sealant. I.e. add water to a water based paint. I'd try a small area and if results are no good, check local DIY shops for "plaster sealer".